# Payout with PayPal

Tags: paypal

I am generating a payout with PayPal to different people. These people provide access to us to their PayPal information to retrieve the necessary information to make the payout. So I am using two different things from PayPal:

- Payouts.
- Log in with PayPal.

To avoid problems when the user change their PayPal email address I am trying to use the recipient type "PAYPAL_ID" when I make the payout. But I have problem to retrieve this information when the user log in with PayPal.

I see the field "PAYER_ID" in [this web site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/) from PayPal but in the [list of scopes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/attributes/) to retrieve each field I don't found the scope for this field.

How can I retrieve this field from PayPal?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in PayPal, for some reason the Sandbox didn't return the PAYER_ID. They updated something in their systems.